# How to find the common node's attributes in Neo4j(CQL)?

Tags: neo4j

How to find the common node in Neo4j ?

I have the following graph : `A->B, B->C, C->D, B->D, A->D`

How to get `D` node values that are common for `A`,`B` and `C`?

Comment: Could you please show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for to this ?

```
MATCH (d:Node)
WHERE 
  exist( (:Node {value:'A'})-->(d)) AND
  exist( (:Node {value:'B'})-->(d)) AND
  exist( (:Node {value:'C'})-->(d))
RETURN d
```

NB: I have added the label `Node` on every node, and the name is in the property `value`. You have to change this value corresponding to your model.

Comment: Thanks Works well :)